# Can't perform translate and alpha animation on Gingerbread

Tags: android, animation

I have the following animation resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/animation_time"
        android:fromXDelta="0%" 
        android:toXDelta="0%" 
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="10%"  />
    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/animation_time"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

I have this animation set on a Dialog, so that when the dialog is dismissed, it shifts down slightly and fades out.  This is working on Android 3.0+, but on pre 3.0 devices, the alpha portion of the animation doesn't do anything.  If I set the duration to a longer time, the dialog doesn't disappear right away, so it seems like it's running, the dialog just isn't fading.  If I comment out the translation, or set the toYDelta value on the translation to 0 (so that there isn't any translation) the alpha works on 2.3.4, it's just when the dialog moves that it won't fade.

Any idea why this is?  I'm having the issue on an HTC Evo 3d, which does have an update available to 4.0, but I've not updated so I can use it as a test device.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into problems when sharing the interpolator. Try setting an interpolator for each animation and not using `android:shareInterpolator`.

Comment: That had the same effect, the translation worked but the alpha didn't.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha animation using floats was only introduced in API Level 11. The setAlpha(int) animation has existed since API Level 1 though. I'm not sure if this will work for XML in the same way it does for the in-built methods, but you could try using integer values "1" and "0" instead of floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an animation that does nothing more than set the alpha to a particular float value. I suspect this is a tad costly of resources since you have to use an animation for each time you set the alpha.

```
public void setLayoutAlpha(float alpha, View v){
    AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
    alphaAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    alphaAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    v.startAnimation(alphaAnim);
}
```

It can be called like so.

```
setLayoutAlpha(1f,viewToChangeAlpha);
```

This is what I used to create a swipeToDismiss layout with fading views that works pre 3.0

Hopefully it will work for whatever you need to use it for.